# Seeing the contents of a memory address in ghidra

Tags: reverse-engineering, binaryfiles, decompiler, ghidra

For a course at university, I am trying to statically analyse a binary with ghidra. In the decompiled code, I have a line like `local_78 = 0x50999c39eefe455c;`

I need to know the content of that local variable / where 0x50999c39eefe455c is pointing at, but when I try to access it, I get a error message "Address not found in program memory".

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: `0x50999c39eefe455c` *is* the content of `local_78`.

Comment: So you are saying this is not an address that is pointing to where the data is stored but it IS the actual data? How can I tell that apart? I just assumed this was an address due to it being exactly 8 bytes